# Sending integer with Python TCP socket and receiving with C# - Error receiving correct data

Tags: python, c#, tcp, bitconverter

I am new to TCP sockets and am trying to use Python (server) to send the size of an encoded image (an integer) with TCP sockets. A C# Winforms application (client) is used to receive this integer but the received int looks to be very random. For example, if the encoded image is `6570`, the C# app receives `808924470`

The Python code (sender):

```
## Connection code...

# Send image size
imageSize = len(encodedImage)
socket.send(str(imageSize).encode("utf-8"))
```

The C# code (receiver):

```
// Connection code...

// Receive int
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesReceived = stream.Read(buffer);
int imageSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);
```

Comment: You were sending a string, not an integer. UTF8(6570) -> 0x30373536 -> 808924470

Comment: C# client should first convert the `byte[]` to a `string` and then use `int.Parse()`. Or better: the python server should send `imageSize` directly without converting it to a string first.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride see also `Utf8Parser`, which is available for every framework version (via the add-in `System.Buffers` package on down-level frameworks); as a side note: sending bytes *directly* requires other considerations, such as CPU-endianness - at that point, I'd be directing people at serializer libraries or comms libraries, for example gRPC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python code is sending the value as UTF string data, i.e. `6570` will be the bytes (as hex) 36-35-37-30. You need to *decode this* as such.

The most efficient approach would be, for example:

```
var bytes = new byte[] { 0x36, 0x35, 0x37, 0x30 };
if (System.Buffers.Text.Utf8Parser.TryParse(bytes, out int value, out int bytesUsed))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Read {value} from {bytesUsed} bytes");
}
```

(you could also use `Encoding.UTF8` to parse the bytes to a `string`, then `int.Parse` to process that `string` to an `int`; `Utf8Parser` is designed to skip the intermediate `string`)

However, you'd also want to consider "framing"; TCP is a stream protocol, not a message protocol. It is not sufficient to just call `Read` - that could be half a message (just the `65`), an entire message, or 57 entire messages and half of the 58th. For a text protocol, something involving line breaks is common.

---

For completeness (to understand what the existing code is doing), `BitConverter.ToInt32` is performing a CPU-endian "pun" (reinterpret-cast) of the bytes to raw integers; since your CPU is most likely little-endian, this is the integer 0x30373536 (remember the UTF8 bytes were hex 36-35-37-30, and little-endianness reverses the perceived byte order), aka the decimal 808924470.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Marc but, I should point out that the image size can vary. Does the above approach account for this? I tried implementing this approach but the output `value` seems to only be `6570`; even if the image size is set to `20`.

Comment: @Slash sorry, I assumed it was obvious but you'd need to pass in the correct buffer to `TryParse`; this might be `new(buffer, 0, bytesReceived)`, but like I say: you'd need to think about "framing"